# An Opam package has been installed but fail to find when compile

Tags: ocaml, opam

I have installed Ocaml and Opam. To compile a project I Opam install a package named **menhir** and successful.
But when I try to make the source file, the error shows
[image: The error]

I have run the eval '...'
and I find it in the package list.
I have tried earlier version, but still.

The makefile equals to:
$ ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -use-menhir -I srz -I lib main.ml

Comment: What exact command do you run to refresh your environment? What is the value of your `$PATH` environment variable? What is the output of `which menhir`?

Comment: All of the commands I applied is
    <br/> **$opam init**  <br/>    **$eval 'opam config env' ** <br/> **$opam depext  conf-m4.l **   <br/> **$opam install menhir**

Comment: There is no output when I use **which menhir**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I need to restart my PC after installing these things. I may start from the install of ocaml so after I restart my machine, it works fine.